# How two join to tables based on the highest value in one of them?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named `Auction` which holds an `auctionID`. I have another table named `bid` which holds the `auctionID` (as a foreign key) and what the amount was.

What I want to do is list the `auctionID` in one column and the amount of the highest bid in the other column.

I have tried different ways of doing inner joins to get this to display properly but failed horribly. Please keep in mind that I'm a total novice when it comes to MYSQL and the solution may very well be that I should go back and redesign the whole database.

The closest I got to display what I want is the two different methods below.

First one

```
SELECT auction.auctionID, bid.bid
from bid
INNER JOIN 
auction on auction.auctionsID = bid.auctionsID;
```

The second one is as follows

```
SELECT auction.auctionsID, bid.bid 
from bid
INNER JOIN 
auction on auction.auctionsID = bid.auctionsID
where bid.bid = (select max(bid.bid) from bid);
```

The first one displays all bids that have been made and what amount they where, but i only want the highest bid on each `auctionID`.

The second one displays only the absolute highest bid ever made on all different auctions and what `auctionID` that specific auction had.

My guess is that i need some sort of nested join statements but I really cant wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: What a great experience. As a long time user that out of desperation created an account today to ask my first question. I got awesome help from this community.

The answer:

```
SELECT auctionid, MAX(bid) as maxbid FROM bid GROUP BY auctionid;
```

Provided by Caius Jard and Deependra Bhandari

Comment: @haag1 MySQL does not support `CROSS APPLY`, and even if it did, I'm not sure you would want to use it here.

Comment: Interesting variation in interpretations of this question - clearly a good example of why Strawberry has the MCVE Q on speed dial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the bids table before you join

```
SELECT * FROM
  auction a
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT auctionid, MAX(bid) as maxbid FROM bid GROUP BY auctionid) b
  on a.auctionid = b.auctionid
```

You'll hence get the details of each auction (including id) and just the maximum bid for each auction

Deependra made a good point; you did say you only really wanted the auctionid and the max bid and this info can be derived solely from the bids table (the subquery aliased as `b` in my code above so if it's truly all you need, strip my query down to just the subquery. If you later want all the other info about an auction, along with its max bid, use the query above

If you want all the auction info and all the maxbid info, for each auction, you can do it thus:

```
SELECT * FROM
  auction a
  INNER JOIN
  bid b 
  ON a.auctionid = b.auctionid
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT auctionid, MAX(bid) as maxbid FROM bid GROUP BY auctionid) mb
  on a.auctionid = mb.auctionid and b.bid = mb.maxbid
```

This will return all the info about an auction and all the info about the max bid. Hopefully you only allow unique bids, otherwise we're going to get into a more complicated "latest" max bid scenario

Comment: Thanks! This help a lot! But it's not exactly what I want. this displays all data that the two tables contain. I only want to show auction.auctionID and bid.bid.

Comment: See the note I made about "just use the subquery" i.e. `SELECT auctionid, MAX(bid) as maxbid FROM bid GROUP BY auctionid` if that's all you want - if you later want more info about the auction or the bid, this is how you can link it in

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    a.auctionID, MAX(b.bid) AS max_bid
FROM auction a
INNER JOIN bid b
    ON a.auctionsID = b.auctionsID
GROUP BY
    a.auctionID;
```

This assumes that you want to find the highest bid for each auction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only two columns and both are available in bid table why you are making join. Use the following one.

SELECT auctionID, max(bid) as Highest_Invoice
from bid
group by auctionID;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull out the `bid` of the bid having the highest amount for a given auction, use a `JOIN` with a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT a.auctionsID, b.bid 
FROM 
    bid
    INNER JOIN auction a
        ON  a.auctionsID = b.auctionsID
        AND b.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM bid WHERE bid = b.bid)
```